# I can't import any files to my javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have added a React to an existing project as shown here: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html
I want to split my component into smaller ones, but it turns out that I can't import any files to my js file (.js .css). When I add import statement, whole code in this file don't work.
My main component questions.js:

```
import RatingScale from "./ratingScale";
import "./style.css"

var questions = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("mydiv").dataset.questions);

class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="question">
        <p>{this.props.content}</p>
        <p>{this.props.id}</p>
        <RatingScale />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Question content={questions[0].question_text} />,
  document.querySelector("#question1")
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Question content={questions[1].question_text} />,
  document.querySelector("#question2")
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Question content="Pytanie 3" />,
  document.querySelector("#question3")
);
```

ratingScale.js:

```
class RatingScale extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="rating_scale">
        <form>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1" />
            <span>1</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad" value="2" />
            <span>2</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad" value="3" />
            <span>3</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad" value="4" />
            <span>4</span>
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="rad" value="5" />
            <span>5</span>
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RatingScale;
```

The code compile but in console I have:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

When I delete imports it works normally. In addition in import when im typing the name of js file it sees it, but it doesn't css files.

Answer (score 0):

The setup instructions for entirely client-side React do not play well with imports. The limitations of that format are such that I think the React website does new developers a serious disservice by even suggesting the approach as a quick start.

Follow the advice in the [Create a New React App](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) page:

> This page describes a few popular React toolchains which help with
> tasks like:
>
> - **Scaling to many files and components**.
> - Using third-party libraries from npm.
> - Detecting common mistakes early.
> - Live-editing CSS and JS in development.
> - Optimizing the output for production.

Use [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app).

Alternatively, you might want to consider [using parcel](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-react-project-with-parcel) which gives a simpler toolchain (but one that isn't as common and well-documented).

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I don't want to create a new app, because Flask is working in the background. I will try to using parcel, maybe it is the solution. Have you any other advise in this situation?

Comment: When you build the app (no matter if you use webpack or parcel), it can be dropped into a page generated by Flask freely. You only need the dev server during development.

Comment: So it is better to create a new React app with create-react-app in an existing project? I don't know if I understood clearly.

Comment: Generally speaking, unless you've already set up a monorepo based system, I would create a React app (and I'd recommend create-react-app to beginners for that) as a parallel project and then pull the built application files into the main project as part of the main project's build process.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't best approach for me, because the Flask part of the project isn't mine and I do not want to break whole repo. I can get around it, but all I need is styling from my style.css file via className property in React. Since I can't import this file and I have linked it in my html file is that any way to use it? Inline styling doesn't help me.